# how to show local file listings with C-x C-f through IVY when starting in a remote file buffer

Tags: tramp, find-file, ivy

System: Mac OSX catalina
Emacs: 26.3

I use Ivy as my completion framework.

Problem is when I am editing a remote buffer over ssh using Tramp, and then I want to look at a file on my local machine.

If I do C-x C-f, I get my dialogue, but I can only see options for the remote machine.  I can't delete my way out of the tramp listings.  So what I do now is I first C-x b into the scratch buffer, then do C-x C-f to see local machine listings.  Is there a way to do this in a more natural fashion?

For example when attached via tramp, hitting backspace/delete at this point does nothing further:

[image: y]

So I go the scratch buffer and then I can get this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this in a more natural fashion?

The best way I know is to type <kbd>~</kbd> twice: the first time will restart completion from your remote home directory, and the second from your local home directory.

Quoth [`(ivy) Using TRAMP`](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#using-tramp):

```
‘/ C-j’
     Move to the local root directory.

‘~~’
     Move to the local home directory.
```

Comment: Oh @Basil thank you!!! This was driving me nuts.
Now let me type some synonims of the question for another pour sool that like me is searchnig for this:
How to get out of tramp?
Tramp how to edit local files?
Tramp insist in using remote server?
Find local files in emacs?